# Como resolver require_once com erro de unexpected T_STATIC em PHP?

Tags: php, nfe

Estou utilizando a biblioteca https://github.com/nfe/client-php da NFe.io para emitir nota fiscal automaticamente quando o retorno do PagSeguro e PayPal for "Pago".

Tente utilizar a chamada de várias formas, de acordo com a documentação:

Com o Composer:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

Sem o Composer, baixando a bibliteca:

```
require_once ('client-php/lib/init.php');
```

E variações dos mesmos como:

```
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/client-php/lib/init.php');
```

Mas sempre me retorna o erro de "unexpected T_STATIC", como mostro a seguir:

```
 <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC in <b>/home/storage/a/f7/10/vovocooks/public_html/temp/client-php/lib/NFe/APIResource.php</b> on line <b>79</b><br />
```

Que já é na biblioteca. Comecei usando ontem, mas hoje (sábado) ninguém deve trabalhar na empresa da NFe.io e preciso dessa ajuda.

Comment: Qual é o conteúdo dessa linha de código? E qual é a versão do PHP que está rodando?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a Versão PHP: 5.2 e a linha é require_once ('client-php/lib/init.php');

Comment: O único requisito da biblioteca, vide repositório, é a versão 5.4 ou superior do PHP. Atualize seu PHP, então.

Comment: Pois é, agora atualizei o PHP e o erro é no    $curl = curl_init($url); retornando Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function  curl_init() in

Comment: Ramos, você precisa configurar seu PHP.ini para liberar a biblioteca do CURL no seu PHP, seja em: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6382581/6510304

Comment: Você possui a extensão cURL instalada? Ela faz parte das dependências da biblioteca. Você chegou a ler o README do repositório ao menos?